# Шаблон проекта Scala + sbt + tomcat + Intellij idea(Servlet, JSP)

Tags: intellij-idea, jsp, tomcat, scala, sbt

Здравствуйте,
подскажите пожалуйста какой нибудть мануал, по созданию web проекта на Scala,
(Scala + sbt + tomcat + Intellij idea(Servlet, JSP)) именно с данными компонентами или опишите процесс создания проекта.

---

P.S. пытался сделать по аналогии как в Java + Maven, но увы не получилось((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web приложения на Scala обыычно не используют Servlet API напрямую. Если это делается, то делается исключительно по умыслу разработчика, и Scala используется так же как любой другой Jvm язык. Вам ничто не мешает писать сервлеты на Clojure или Groovy. Используете язык так же как вы бы использовали Java.

Однако, в мире Scala вообще принято не использовать серверы приложений. В первую очередь из-за того что они усложняют "деплоймент" (развертывание) приложения, так же как и замедляют процесс разработки. Конечно же существуют фреймворки которые полагаются на Servlet Api, но сам доступ к сервлетам там глубоко скрыт от разработчика. Обратите ваше внимение на [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/) насколько мне известно он поддерживает возможность работать с серверами приложений и сервлетами, но не напрямую.

Что же принято в мире Scala? Сейчас стандартом де-факто является [Play framerowk](https://www.playframework.com/). Вы можете скачать и установить его в качестве части платформы [Activator](http://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt).

Активатор -- это приложение которое содержит ряд готовых шаблонов для конкретных типов приложений: web-приложения, SWING приложения и другие. Устанавливаете typesafe интересующий вас шаблон скачиваете его и используете.

IntelliJ IDEA может спокойно подхватить любой sbt/gradle/maven проект (а activator предлагает только шаблоны использующие sbt) если конечно же для нее предустановлен Scala plugin. (Scala plguin для IntelliJ IDEA включает в себя поддержку sbt). Поддержка Play framework доступна только в платной (Ultimate) версии IntelliJ IDEA. Бесплатная поддержка Play Framework есть у [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/), надеюсь данная информация вам поможет